# Error with docker compose and Github Action

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, github-actions

I am trying to run the following GitHub action workflow.

The docker-compose file contains the following Python backend services and Vue frontend services.

The workflow should build a docker composer file and upload it to the registry.

I am following the structure of the GitHub Publish Docker Container WorkFlow template.

The following is the yaml file that is giving the problem.

```
name: Docker

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '42 6 * * *'
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
    tags: [ 'v*.*.*' ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  integration:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/python-app.yml
    permissions:
      contents: read
      checks: write
      
  build:
    needs: [integration]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
      id-token: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install cosign
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: sigstore/cosign-installer@v3.1.1
        with:
          cosign-release: 'v2.1.1'

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3.0.0

      - name: Log into registry ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@v3.0.0
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract Docker metadata
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v5.0.0
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

      - name: Build with Docker Compose
        run: docker-compose build

      - name: Push Docker images with Docker Compose
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        run: |
            docker-compose push backend
            docker-compose push frontend

      - name: Sign the published Docker image
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        run: |
          TAGS="${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}"
          for tag in ${TAGS}; do
            cosign sign --yes ${tag}
          done
```

Error

```
Run TAGS="ghcr.io/zentri-analytics/jamaica-dividend-platform:main"
  TAGS="ghcr.io/zentri-analytics/jamaica-dividend-platform:main"
  for tag in ${TAGS}; do
    cosign sign --yes ${tag}
  done
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    REGISTRY: ghcr.io
    IMAGE_NAME: Zentri-Analytics/jamaica-dividend-platform
    DOCKER_METADATA_OUTPUT_VERSION: main
    DOCKER_METADATA_OUTPUT_TAGS: ghcr.io/zentri-analytics/jamaica-dividend-platform:main
    DOCKER_METADATA_OUTPUT_LABELS: org.opencontainers.image.created=2024-01-02T00:31:00.337Z
  org.opencontainers.image.description=
  org.opencontainers.image.licenses=
  org.opencontainers.image.revision=d901c48c927572b7a70de2d4beb19f2c11976b85
  org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/Zentri-Analytics/jamaica-dividend-platform
  org.opencontainers.image.title=jamaica-dividend-platform
  org.opencontainers.image.url=https://github.com/Zentri-Analytics/jamaica-dividend-platform
  org.opencontainers.image.version=main
    DOCKER_METADATA_OUTPUT_JSON: {"tags":["ghcr.io/zentri-analytics/jamaica-dividend-platform:main"],"labels":{"org.opencontainers.image.created":"2024-01-02T00:31:00.337Z","org.opencontainers.image.description":"","org.opencontainers.image.licenses":"","org.opencontainers.image.revision":"d901c48c927572b7a70de2d4beb19f2c11976b85","org.opencontainers.image.source":"https://github.com/Zentri-Analytics/jamaica-dividend-platform","org.opencontainers.image.title":"jamaica-dividend-platform","org.opencontainers.image.url":"https://github.com/Zentri-Analytics/jamaica-dividend-platform","org.opencontainers.image.version":"main"}}
    DOCKER_METADATA_OUTPUT_BAKE_FILE: /tmp/docker-actions-toolkit-oun47E/docker-metadata-action-bake.json
Generating ephemeral keys...
Retrieving signed certificate...
Successfully verified SCT...
WARNING: Image reference ghcr.io/zentri-analytics/jamaica-dividend-platform:main uses a tag, not a digest, to identify the image to sign.
    This can lead you to sign a different image than the intended one. Please use a
    digest (example.com/ubuntu@sha256:abc123...) rather than tag
    (example.com/ubuntu:latest) for the input to cosign. The ability to refer to
    images by tag will be removed in a future release.

Error: signing [ghcr.io/zentri-analytics/jamaica-dividend-platform:main]: accessing entity: entity not found in registry
main.go:74: error during command execution: signing [ghcr.io/zentri-analytics/jamaica-dividend-platform:main]: accessing entity: entity not found in registry
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```